# issue post a resource with lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

Im having a problem for creating a resource, when i make a POST request to my route. 
My route looks like:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'oauth'), function()
{
    //Media Route
    Route::resource('media', 'PostController',['except' => ['create', 'edit']]);
});
```

when i post the resource it says i should provide an valid access token, but i already doing that. This is the resource uri.

appname.dev/api/v1/media/?access_token=ksfdkfjkfsj

even with: 
appname.dev/api/v1/media?access_token=ksfdkfjkfsj

it doesn't work it throws an error with json response

```
"error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"access token\" parameter."
```

I'm testing this with the Postman plugin in chrome and using the lucadegasperi oauth2-server package for laravel.

What am i doing wrong?

Thx in advance

Comment: I solved the problem by myself. You've to put the access token in de header included with the type of the token. 

for example:

Authorization: Bearer accesstokenhere